# How much Hit Points does casting a two action heightened 2-nd level Heal restore?

Tags: spells, healing, pathfinder-2e

[Heal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=148)

> You channel positive energy to heal the living or damage the undead. If the target is a willing living creature, you restore 1d8 Hit Points.

> Two Actions (somatic, verbal) The spell has a range of 30 feet. If you're healing a living creature, increase the Hit Points restored by 8.

> Heightened (+1) The amount of healing or damage increases by 1d8, and the extra healing for the 2-action version increases by 8.

I'm reading this as a two action heightened 2-nd level Heal restoring 2d8+16 Hit Points. Am I interpreting this correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You heal 2d8+16

You link all the relevant information... you heal for 1d8 (+8 for using the 2-Action version) and increase it by 1d8+8 for casting it Heightened to 2nd level. This trend continues all the way through 10th level spells to 10d8+80.

The Heighten ability is specifically 1d8 *and* +8.

Comment: I guess I just wanted confirmation. Mind stuck in old versions of D&D and Pathfinder.

Comment: @Linus I find the nuances of Heightened spells to be one of the hardest things in 2e. you have three different versions of Heightening - Heightened (+X), Heightened (Xth), and spells with no Heightened changes except they are now a higher level (as in 1e). +X provides a benefit (usually more damage or healing) for every slot above the base, (Xth) provides different benefits at different 'breakpoints' (eg Invisibility acting as previous Greater Invis), and spells with no Heighten effect may still make them useful for Counteract (eg Dispel) and Incapacitate purposes.